# Compress images without reading into memory

Tags: android, android-bitmap, image-compression

I have a big image file on sd card, which I want to compress before uploading to server. But to compress image using `Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat format, int quality, OutputStream stream)`, we need to read image into memory and save the compressed version.
Is there a way to generate a compressed version of an image without reading bitmap into memory.

I'm using following code for compression.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;

Bitmap finalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(originalFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);    

File local = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),  "/my_images");
local.mkdirs();
File compressedFile = new File(local, "test.jpg");
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(compressedFile);
finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, out);
```

Comment: Save the bitmap on disk and compress the file.

Comment: Image is already saved on disk and it's about 100MB in size. So I don't want to load bitmap into memory as it will cause OOM. What I need is to create a compressed version of file, to optimize the upload time.

Comment: in which format are you uploading your image?

Comment: Is there any value in compressing the image on the device in the first place? I mean upload it to the server and compress it there if needed - it will have vastly superior resources surely?

Comment: 100mb? what is the resolution of the image?

Comment: @MarkKeen I need to optimize the upload time that's why compression is needed at client.

Comment: @MohammedAtif It's JPG file and resolution is 7787 × 11601. Actually this is a test file but my app is expected to face huge files is real use-cases.

Comment: thats too huge for an image file. how about using svg file instead of that big jpeg?

Comment: Use a zip compression routine on the image file as suggested. Not sure how you'll compress it much more if it's already a jpeg - without losing significant quality that is - also by the time it's compressed you could have uploaded the image - I'm guessing with imagery that size you'll use wi-fi.

Comment: @MohammedAtif we can't restrict the input images' types by the user.

Comment: i never saw any ideal android user having 100mb jpeg file on his phone. your current problem is more of handling the input rather than the upload. can you please provide more details about the image. like what data does it hold and how it is generated, etc.

Answer (score -1):

BitmapFactory can resize an image file while reading from disk. You end up with a small bitmap. Then compress that bitmap to file and upload that file.

Comment: I don't want to downscale the image, instead I need to have original scale image with some compression to reduce size/upload time.

Comment: jpeg is the best compression you can do on mobile side. even after that if it is 100 mb, then somwthing is wrong with how you are generating the image @Ammar

Comment: `I need to have original scale image with some compression to reduce size/upload time. `. Impossible. A jpg is already maximum compressed. Size can only be reduced for less quality. But for that you first have to create that impossible bitmap. It is terrible how you formulated your problem.

Comment: @MohammedAtif I've updated to question to include the code I'm using to compress image. Question is not about what's the best compression method. The question is how to to jpeg compression without loading bitmap from image file.

Comment: @greenapps Input image can be anything, not necessarily JPG.

Comment: @Ammar , my question is where did you manage to find 100mb image file on Android device? I know you have some assumptions regarding solution already in your mind, but you will not find the ideal solution unless you stop defending your image and start providing more information about it.